# Change bbcode depending on url value

Tags: php, preg-replace, bbcode

I'm using preg_replace with an array to go through my bbcode and make the change when a news entry is posted.

For example

```
$bbcode = array (
    "/\[url\=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/is" => "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$2</a>"
);
```

So then when I pull data from the database (in this example $newsPost) which contains the text and bbcode, I do this.

```
$newsPost  = preg_replace(array_keys($bbcode), array_values($bbcode), $newsPost);
```

Now, what I'd like is to find out if the value of $1 contains my domain, the target should be "top" and if not, it should be blank.

So if we have `[url=http://www.mydomain.com]visit our page[/url]`. then it's transformed to `<a href="http://www.mydomain.com" target="top">visit our page</a>` and anything else will have `target="_blank"`.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED/FIXED**

- Added `str_replace()` to deal with dots in domain names
- Initially I fixed your backslashes (if you want a literal backslash in your Regex it should be `\\` in the string) but I have undone this as you have said it was working for you in the first place.

---

How about this?

```
$mydomain = 'domain.tld';
$bbcode = array (
  "/\[url\=([^]]*)(".str_replace('.','\\.',$mydomain).")([^]]*)\]([^[]*)\[\/url\]/is" => "<a href='$1$2$3' target='top'>$4</a>",
  "/\[url\]([^[]*)(".str_replace('.','\\.',$mydomain).")([^[]*)\[\/url\]/is" => "<a href='$1$2$3' target='top'>$1$2$3</a>";
  "/\[url\=([^]]*)\]([^[]*)\[\/url]/is" => "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$2</a>"
  "/\[url\]([^[]*)\[\/url\]/is" => "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>",
);
```

If that will work for you, a caveat: Don't set `$mydomain` to `www.domain.tld`, set it to `domain.tld`, so you catch all subdomains.

You could even do it with multiple domains like this:

```
$mydomains = array(
  'domain.tld',
  'anotherdomain.tld',
  'sub.yetanotherdomain.tld'
);

// Add domain-specific rules before general rules so we don't match domain
// specific links with the general link rule (we have replaced them by that point)
$domainrules = array();
foreach ($mydomains as $domain) {
  $domainrules["/\[url\=([^]]*)(".str_replace('.','\\.',$domain).")([^]]*)\]([^[]*)\[\/url\]/is"] = "<a href='$1$2$3' target='top'>$4</a>";
  $domainrules["/\[url\]([^[]*)(".str_replace('.','\\.',$domain).")([^[]*)\[\/url\]/is"] = "<a href='$1$2$3' target='top'>$1$2$3</a>";
}

// This array contains all your static BBCode rules
$staticrules = array(
  "/\[url\=([^]]*)\]([^[]*)\[\/url\]/is" => "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$2</a>",
  "/\[url\]([^[]*)\[\/url\]/is" => "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>",
  "/\[b\]([^[]*)\[\/b\]/is" => "<span class='bold_text'>$1</span>",
  ...
);

// Make an array that contains all the rules
$bbcode = array_merge($staticrules,$domainrules);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thank you. A little unsure about the second example. If I have a lot of items in bbcode (20+), I'd have to rewrite each to fit the $bbcode[] style?

Comment: @scatteredbomb No, you can use [array_merge()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), see my updated answer

Comment: @scatteredbomb just edited again, I just realised you will need to account for people using `[url]http://my.url/[/url]` syntax, as well as `[url=http://my.url/]some text[/url]`

Comment: @scatteredbomb You are leaving yourself open to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks with this, you could do with adding a rule that will disallow any links that start with `javascript:`, for example you could convert them to `<span class="illegal_link">This link is not allowed and was blocked<span>`.

Comment: Something isn't working right. If a post has a "mydomain" link, the next link doesn't show properly. Example, it'll print out the HTML like this `<a href='http://www.test.com]Here's a link[/url]`whic obviously leads to a broken link with whatever text inside. So it'll show the first link perfectly with the '_top' target and everything. But the NEXT link displays like the example.

Comment: I did wonder if you might have that problem, what you will have to do is use a negated character class (like `[^]]*`) instead of `.*?` to match the data fields you want. See updated answer. Also, you might be interested in [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) for playing around with it and seeing exactly what it matches.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much for your help, you've been incredibly helpful. Wish I could give you more rep!